# boost::shared_ptr and Return Type Resolver idiom

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, operator-keyword, ambiguity

I am currently working on a concept of Object known in Java or C# for C++. It would be similar to variant type like boost::any, however having wider functionality. For that purpose I am using `boost::shared_ptr` to internaly store actual data and I wanted to provide Return Type Resolver idiom for easily obtaining this data, as it is stored in actual implementation. I know I could use `boost::shared_ptr` automatic conversion during assigment operator or constructor but as I said `shared_ptr` is not avaiable at this stage.

Implementing RtR I have encountered a problem with linux platform. For simplicity of code I provide just a simple code which reflects what I want to do basically and what is working under VS2010 and not under GCC. Any comments or solutions woud be appriciate.

```
struct RtR
{
    template<typename Ptr>
    operator Ptr()
    {
        return Ptr();
    }

    template<typename Ptr>
    operator Ptr() const
    {
        return Ptr();
    }
};

class TestRtR
{
    void test()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<int> intPtr(new int);
        intPtr = get();
    }

    void test() const
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<const int> intPtr(new int);
        intPtr = get();
    }

    RtR get()
    {
        RtR ret;
        return ret;
    }

    const RtR get() const
    {
        const RtR ret;
        return ret;
    }
};
```

As I said - if You compile it under VS2010 everything goes ok, but under linux I get:

```
In member function ‘void TestRtR::test()':
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘intPtr = TestRtR::get()’
note: candidates are:
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) [with T = int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<int>]
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(boost::shared_ptr<T>&&) [with T = int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<int>]
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t) [with T = int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<int>, boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
In member function ‘void TestRtR::test() const’:
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘intPtr = TestRtR::get()’
note: candidates are:
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) [with T = const int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<const int>]
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(boost::shared_ptr<T>&&) [with T = const int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<const int>]
note: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t) [with T = const int, boost::shared_ptr<T> = boost::shared_ptr<const int>, boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
```

Are definitions of `boost::shared_ptr` different under GCC and VS2010? What is the ground of this ambiguity and how to solve it?

Comment: [coliru compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cfb07783df63c2c163ff1c0175f1ea57-7f8268409eb03791e90782252574997f) this just fine, which version of boost are you using?

Comment: 1.54, I am using automated build system which gets boost code from their repository: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.6.4. I see You are using -std=c++11 switch, in our case it is -std=c++0x. Maybe that`s the case? Or different gcc version?

Comment: Changing your code to std::shared_ptr does not cause the error when using gcc. I suspect the third boost constructor is causing the ambiguity. RValue reference should be preferred over LValue reference, but I'm not sure whether int is convertible to sp_nullptr_t. Perhaps a later version of GCC?