# Avoid repeating the variable type: Return Type Resolver, C++11 auto, ...anything else?

Tags: c++, c++11, dry, auto, return-type

Let's say I have the following template function:

```cpp
// #include <iostream>

template< typename T >
T read( std::istream& in )
{
    T x;
    in >> x;  // (could check for failure, but not the point)
    return x;
}
```

It is intended to be used like this (to initialize `const` variables from user input):

```cpp
// #include <string>
// std::istream& in = std::cin;

const int integer = read< int >( in );
const double decimal = read< double >( in );
const std::string word = read< std::string >( in );
...
```

But note that the same type must be provided *twice*: once for the variable declaration, and once again for the call. Such a duplication would be better avoided (see also [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), "Don't Repeat Yourself"), because each change has to be duplicated, and for example code like this:

```cpp
const int integer = read< double >( in );
const double decimal = read< int >( in );
const std::string word = read< char* >( in );
```

compiles "fine" but will probably do bad things at runtime (especially the third one, which causes a warning).

**Is there a way to avoid the type repetition?**

---

I can already think of two ways, so instead of pretending I don't know them I'm quickly exposing them before asking for more:

1. **Return Type Resolver**

   I recently discovered [the **"Return Type Resolver" idiom**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Return_Type_Resolver) (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981131/boostshared-ptr-and-return-type-resolver-idiom)). So we can create a simple class with a *template implicit conversion operator* around the existing function:

   ```cpp
   class Read {
       std::istream& m_in;
   public:
       explicit Read( std::istream& in ) : m_in( in ) { }

       template< typename T >
       operator T() const
       {
           return read< T >( m_in );
       }
   };
   ```

   And we can now write code like this:

   ```cpp
   const int integer = Read( in );
   const double decimal = Read( in );
   const std::string word = Read( in );
   ...
   ```

   where the "return type" is automatically deduced from the variable type (note: the return type is not `const` even if the variable is, so this is truly equivalent to the original code (especially after the probable inlining)).
2. **C++11 `auto`**

   Starting from **C++11** we can use [the **`auto`** specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) as an alternative, which also avoids naming the type twice, but the approach is "inverse":

   ```cpp
   const auto integer = read< int >( in );
   const auto decimal = read< double >( in );
   const auto word = read< std::string >( in );
   ...
   ```

   where the variable type is automatically deduced from the return type.

**Anything else?**

Now, do you know of other alternatives? *[In case you wonder, see my replies to comments below for the "why" of this question.]*

Thank you.

Comment: Why does there *need* to be anything else?

Comment: I would say, that's about it really.

Comment: @NicolBolas I never intended that there _need_ to be something else, I just _asked_ for _possibly_ other solutions. I like to learn you see :) But I edited the title ("what else?" -> "anything else?"). That's also because I knew of `auto` for a time but only recently discovered the RTR idiom, so there _might_ be others ways I never heard of

Comment: @gx_ ok then, what problems do you face that another solution would solve?

Comment: Well, you can still use the preprocessor, but I guess, you won't like this approach: `#define READ(type, variable, stream) type variable = read<type>(stream)` Then you can do `READ(int, integer, in);`

Comment: (I guess that if I had just asked for a way to avoid repetition, without mentioning the solutions I currently know (or maybe just one of them) I wouldn't have got that vote to close :'( _\*cries\*_) @Yakk Nothing special, but I don't really like `auto` _for this precise example_ (I find that the type is less easily readable than with RTR), and RTR adds a bit of "boilerplate" (just a bit, admittedly). @cmaster That's an answer, thank you! "+1"! :) (but you guessed right ^^)

Comment: @cmaster Please could you make your comment an answer? so that it is more visible (and I can upvote it). It is a correct answer, after all =) (I had completely forgotten about macros when writing the question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can still use the preprocessor, even though you might not like it for stylistic reasons. You could use it like this:

```
#define READ(type, variable, stream) type variable = read<type>(stream)
```

After this, you can write your assignments simply as

```
READ(int, integer, in);
```

Of course, this hides the definition of a variable and its initialization behind a function-like construct, which I do not like, but it's a possible solution.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about those old macros! That was simple though... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to package the boilerplate up in one spot for every return type deduction function:

```
// usual sequence boilerplate:
template<unsigned... s> struct seq { typedef seq<s...> type; };
template<unsigned max, unsigned... s > struct make_seq:make_seq<max-1, max-1, s...> {};
template<unsigned... s> struct make_seq<0, s...>:seq<s...> {};

// RTR object, which wraps a functor F to do return type deduction:
template<template<typename>class F>
struct RTR {
  // Stores a `tuple` of arguments, which it forwards to F when cast to anything:
  template<typename... Args>
  struct worker {
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
    worker ( Args&&... a ):args(std::forward<Args>(a)...) {}
    template<typename T, unsigned... s>
    T call(seq<s...>) const {
      return F<T>()( std::forward<Args>(std::get<s>(args))... );
    }
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
      return call<T>(make_seq<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }
  };
  // Here operator() creates a worker to hold the args and do the actual call to F:
  template<typename... Args>
  worker<Args...> operator()( Args&&... args ) const {
    return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  }
};

// We cannot pass function templates around, so instead we require stateless functors:
template<typename T>
struct read {
  T operator()( std::istream& in ) const {
    T x;
    in >> x;
    return x;
  }
};

// and here we introduce reader, a return type deducing wrapper around read:
namespace { RTR<read> reader; }
```

You'd have to write a lot of return type deducing code for the above boilerplate to be less than the boilerplate for each specific use.

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply) Thank you! =) Your code had a couple typos (missing '`;`' after `struct seq` definition, and `worker` constructor named `RTR`) but after fixing them it works like a charm: [live example](http://ideone.com/NGbYlX). Now that's indeed a lot of code ^^ but it only needs to be written once. (It may be worth noting that, like `auto`, this is a C++11 solution, because C++98/03 doesn't have variadic templates, `std::tuple` or `std::forward`.)

Comment: use `boost::tuple`.  Perfect forwarding isn't possible, but imperfect forwarding is.  And you can replace the variardic `template`s with 0 through 10 custom versions of massive massive boilerplate, possibly generated by `BOOST` macros.  ;)

Comment: You are resourceful. ;) Thank you once more